# Expression taking and Calculation

Tags: python, math

I am a newbie in python. Learning day by day. I am trying to take an expression like this **(4+10)+3*89-12** from user and show him the answer only. Also if he inputs something like this **(4+10)+3*89-12(45-2** it will show an error as he didn't close braces.

I searched on google but I didn't get any solution. Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You most likely simply want to use the `eval` function for that. [See Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tour.
“Hep me to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.
We expect you to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question
about your algorithm or technique you include in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
# get the user‘s input
expression = input("Enter your expression here: ")
# as expression will be a string, you can use the eval to evaluate it. (Note that eval has got some problems, but it‘s the easiest way if it‘s just a simple program.)
try:
    answer = eval(expression)
    print(answer)
# Now you can include some exceptions:
except SyntaxError:
    print("Syntax Error!")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Division by 0!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, will work fine.

```
s = input()
try:
    print(eval(s))
except:
    print("There is error in input")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try `eval('(4+10)+3*89-12(45-2')` you get a SyntaxError and catch it with try except

```
try:
    value = eval('(4+10)+3*89-12(45-2')
except SyntaxError:
    print('error')
```

However, you can use some functions like this:

```
# Function to check parentheses 
def check(myStr): 
    open_list = ["("] 
    close_list = [")"] 
    stack = [] 
    for i in myStr: 
        if i in open_list: 
            stack.append(i) 
        elif i in close_list: 
            pos = close_list.index(i) 
            if ((len(stack) > 0) and
                (open_list[pos] == stack[len(stack)-1])): 
                stack.pop() 
            else: 
                # not have open or close parentheses
                return False
    if len(stack) == 0:
        # open and close parentheses present 
        return True
    else: 
        return False
 
 check('()') True
 check('(noclosed') False
```

or this:

```
def check(my_string): 
    brackets = ['()', '{}', '[]'] 
    while any(x in my_string for x in brackets): 
        for br in brackets: 
            my_string = my_string.replace(br, '') 
    return not my_string 

 check('()') True
 check('(noclosed') False
```

**Remenber that the parametrer passed to check function must to be an string**

I hope I was helpful